# How to efficiently locate malware on an endpoint?

Tags: malware, antimalware, detection

I have a question from one of the interviews I had, I have no knowledge in system security and so I didn't know how to approach each. The question was:

> A customer suspects that one of his endpoints got infected by malware (OS is Windows 10 x64), and you were asked to analyze it.
>
> Build an analysis plan from the simplest techniques to
>   more advanced methods. Try to focus on the most efficient and
>   effective methods for detecting the malware.
>
> Avoid mentioning other trivial stuff like checking Firewall Settings
>   or Security Updates, but rather concentrate on finding the malware.

I tried to look on the internet but couldn't find anything useful except for the same solutions of using Malwarebytes or similar programs. I guess it's not what's done in real situation when there is limited time to locate and isolate the malware.

Can someone tell me what are the key points to start with, or how to approach this?

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing this. Too many to cover in this question format. I think what you are looking for is 'malware forensics'. You should be able to find more material on the internet with that search term.

Comment: I think the "focus on the most efficient and effective methods" sets the constraints nicely for this question, @schroeder.

Comment: Run Spyware Terminator, Malwarebytes and Hitman.

Comment: @Overmind so, your answer is, "run anti-malware"?

Comment: @Overmind Blindly installing third-party tools in the hopes of remediating the box skips the entire analysis requirement. If your toolseat included a recent version of CCleaner, you'd be even more hosed.

Comment: I never used CCleaner due to its general spam-like behavior and untrusted rating.

Comment: @ schroeder yes, you can't really do much without a specialized crew on this. Anyway, one simple way of detecting anything is knowing where all your files suppose to be and what CRC they have. This can even be done with a .batch file.

Answer (score 3):

> from one of the interviews I had, I have no knowledge in system security

I know several people with CISSPs who would struggle to answer the question competently - what was the interview for? Really my question is what level of skill/effort is expected by the person asking the question?

> trivial stuff like checking Firewall Settings or Security Updates

That's a rather strange thing to say. if the interviewees *first* response was to start looking at the infection vector then the interviewer should be questioning their approach. OTOH, I would consider evaluating the infection vector a useful method of identifying possible candidates for the malware.

You should always start with the obvious/cheap checks:

> A customer suspects that one of his endpoints got infected by malware

My first step would be to establish **why** the customer suspects that. From then on subsequent steps branch out - there is not a single path which lead you to the answer in every case. You prioritize actions which will maximize the amount of information about the malware for the minimum amount of effort / cost.

Some of the things to look at:

- is there a time when the system was in a known good state?

  - what files have changed since the known good state?
- is there anti-malware installed on the system

  - is it working

    - if not, when did it stop
  - is it reporting anything
- what processes are running?

  - how does this compare to a similar system which is not infected

etc.

At some point you may have to intervene with the operation of the system. While this is perhaps beyond the scope of the answer expected by the interviewer, it is essential to preserve the state of the machine before the intervention in order to identify the malware - even if we're not talking about a crime scene, mapping out the cause/effect network often requires backtracking.